# How would I add a class on leave of a page and remove on return to the same page?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

js and onleave of a page I am adding a class when the user scrolls to the next page. How would I remove this class on return to the page and add a new class instead? How could I create an array of the pages and depending on which page they are on, I can target specific elements and add/remove class accordingly?

```
var delay = 700; //milliseconds
var timeoutId;
var animationIsFinished = false;
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
        var curTime = new Date().getTime();
        $('.footage').css('background-image','url(./img/neonLogo.gif)');
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            animationIsFinished = true;
            fullpage_api.moveTo(destination.index + 1);
        }, delay);
        return animationIsFinished;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of the [state classes added by fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) such as `fp-viewing-SECTION-SLIDE` ones added to the `body`?

See my video regarding how to create css3 animations using them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for the advice, this should help me complete what I am trying to achieve. The only thing is in my body I do no have the class"fp-viewing-0" i have the following. Am I missing something?

<body class="fp-viewing-code" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;">

Comment: hey ignore last message, this is because I have changed the data-anchors,